# CodeIgniter mod-rewrite doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am trying to host my web project, which is created with CI, but I guess it's something wrong with my .htacess file or could it be like that, that hosting providers server apache rewrite model is disabled? How can I fix this?
Result, which I am getting right now is an empty page.
You can see it right here - [my project](http://probasketpicks.com/basketball/)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /basketball/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
 
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
 
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Maybe you have other ideas, where the problem is? Thanks for help.

Comment: getting a 500 error on page serve. What happens if you kill the htaccess? (still 500?)

Comment: Does your index file reside in: mydomain.com/basketball/index.php? If it doesn't (belongs at the root of your hosting) then your RewriteBase is pointing every request to a non-existent index.php. Start by commenting out the RewriteBase line

Comment: I has tried to write "RewriteBase index.php/basketball/", "RewriteBase probasketpicks.com/basketball/", but I think that is incorrect tries, so than I got 500 error. When I delete my .htacess I get the same blank page.

Comment: Big Chris it does. My index.php is in probasketpicks.com/basketball/index.php

Comment: you can try to change the line $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; in config file to $config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: $config['index_page'] is empty

Comment: I know where is the problem. Server don't let to AllowOverride All. I appended 
<Directory>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
to my .htacess and now I'm getting 500 error. Please help me.